# Mod RewriteRule or RedirectMatch

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following situation in a website:

```
DOMAIN.com/shop/page/116/?orderby=date
DOMAIN.com/shop/page/116/?orderby=menu_order
DOMAIN.com/shop/page/116/?orderby=price
```

DOMAIN.com/shop/page/116/?orderby=XXXX

The XXXX values changes, and no matter what the XXXX values are the page have to go back to /shop/

I need to have a best solution to handle all FUTURE requests sent to any of the above format.

The real range of the shop its from shop/page/1-68/ all pages > = 69-150 are not available yet indexed.

I need to redirect any page in the format 
`DOMAIN.com/shop/page/69/?orderby=xxxxxx to /shop/` excluding all existing shop pages the range 1-68.

I had made some attempts with:

```
(\/[\/\w]+\/[\w]+[\d])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing down every possible digit combination in the `.htaccess` file, I'd use

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^shop/page/.+ /shop/ [R,L]
```

... and check the url programmatically afterwards (ie serving the content from page 1-68 and presenting an index for 69-150).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the url programatically check?